# Optics surface equation to quadric form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, surfaces, quadrics

This should be straightforward, but honestly I forgot even the names Google for...

I've got a surface description in this form (what is it called?):

$$z=\dfrac{cr^2}{1+\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2}},$$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This form is standard in optics. How can it be converted to the quadric form? I need it to [program ray-tracing](http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/graphics/quadrics.html), and I haven't used the quadric form since university.

Answer (score 0):

$$z=\dfrac{cr^2}{1+\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2}},$$

rationalise the denominator

$$
z = \frac{cr^2\left(1+\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2}\right)}{\left(1-\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2}\right)\left(1+\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2}\right)} \\
=\frac{cr^2\left(1+\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2}\right)}{(1+k)c^2r^2} \tag{1}
$$

then re-write Eq.(1) as 
$$
cr^2\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2} = z(1+k)c^2r^2 - cr^2 
$$
I think you can take it from here right?

$\textbf{Update:}$

since the OP has disappeared and no complete answer (or at least I think its an answer)
$$
\sqrt{1-(1+k)c^2r^2} = z(1+k)c - 1 
$$
thus
$$
1 - (1+k)c^2r^2 = \left(z(1+k)c - 1 \right)^2 = c^2(1+k)^2z^2 -2c(1+k)z+1\\
\implies (1+k)c^2r^2 + c^2(1+k)^2z^2 -2c(1+k)z=Ar^2 + Bz^2+Cz = 0\
$$

Comment: It seems like, if one is willing to shift the  origin, then the best quadric form is simply $$(z(1+k)c-1)^2+(1+k) c^2 r^2=1$$ i.e. a circle centered at $(z,r)=\left(\dfrac{1}{c(1+k)},0\right)$.

Comment: @semiclassical you strike again. I love the simplicity of your result. You should put that as answer please :). Though the OP has seemed to have disappeared.

Comment: Heh, maybe! Though I actually didn't go far enough: since $r^2=x^2+y^2$ in the OP, it's an ellipsoid with circular horizontal cross-sections with major $z$-axis. (Cutely, its bottom tip sits at the origin since $r=0\implies z=0$.)

Comment: You know whats really funny (in a sad kind of way) I did not even see that the first time round.